# How to smooth transition from one colour to another on hovering?

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

I have the following code in which when the circle is hovered, its size is increased (enlarged) and it does that smoothly in 2 seconds. At the same time, the circle also changes its background colour from black to white but that is done abruptly, see:

```css
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
color: white;
background-color: black;
border: 2px solid white;
position: relative;
right: -250px;
bottom: -150px;
border-radius: 50%;
transition: width 2s, height 2s;

}
div:hover {
background-color: white;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: purple">

<div></div>

</body>
```

However, I would like the transition from black to white to be smooth. I came up with one solution, that is, add `transition: all 2s ease;`to `div` in CSS:

```css
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
color: white;
background-color: black;
border: 2px solid white;
position: relative;
right: -250px;
bottom: -150px;
border-radius: 50%;
transition: width 2s, height 2s;
transition: all 2s ease;


}
div:hover {
background-color: white;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: purple">

<div></div>

</body>
```

but there are two `transition` attributes in the DIV section of the CSS and I'm skeptical about that. Is there any other way to get round it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to achieve!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: purple;
}

.container .circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
  transition: transform 2s ease, background-color 2s 250ms ease;
}

.container .circle:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did what he **@pr0grammar** wanted to do on the first place with some minor improvements.

Comment: I meant explaining it in English would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons you are better off declaring each individual property you would like to be affected by the transition. Think of it as a whitelist of properties you want to toggle. So your final transition rule could look like: `transition: width 2s, height 2s, background 2s;`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `transition-timing-function` to `ease`.
[Refer this example for various timing functions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition_speed)

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
  position: relative;
  right: -250px;
  bottom: -150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: purple">

  <div></div>

</body>
```

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul According to the question, the animation is already working per desire and the question was due to the concern for duplication of `transition` property when he wanted the transition to take place in the `ease` timing function. So the solution is using `transition-timing-function`

Comment: Sorry. I deleted my previous comment because I think it's my mobile phone that's not showing the smoothness.